# Limit[Sum[(2*E*n)^w/(w^(n/2+w)), {w,2,n}],n->Infinity]

Tags: summation, sequence

I would like to show that the following (and other similar formulae) tends to zero.

```
Limit[Sum[(2*E*n)^w/(w^(n/2+w)), {w,2,n}],n->Infinity]
```

What's the right way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: You can play around with `ExpToTrig`

Comment: If you `DiscretePlot` your sum you will see that the limit seems to be 0. Proving that (by hand) is rather easy afterwards.

Comment: @A.G. If you change the problem just slightly to Limit[Sum[(2*E*n)^w/(w^(n/4+w)), {w,2,n}],n->Infinity]  it is much less obvious how to solve it by plotting.